# How can my Greasemonkey script auto-reload a page, and auto-click a button?

Tags: javascript, click, greasemonkey, reload

I'm a beginner in JavaScript.  I need to know if this is possible and then if so, how to do it.

I'd like to create a Greasemonkey script that will automatically reload a webpage every hour, and then after reloading the page, I'd like it to click a button for me.

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, using `addEventListener`, `setTimeout` and `click`.

Comment: So how would I start this?  Is it possible to set it to reload and click at a random interval?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- For clicking stuff, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8192413/331508).
- See also [a javascript reference for `location.reload()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp).
- See also [a better javascript reference for `setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout).
- Since the button may be loaded via AJAX (Need more information in the question), reference [the `waitForKeyElements()` utility](https://gist.github.com/2625891), for dealing with AJAX delays/modifications.
- Start learning [jQuery](http://jquery.com/); it will save you a ton of grief and effort.
- Identify the jQuery selector for the button you want.  You can use tools like *Firebug* to help with this (Note that jQuery selectors and CSS selectors are mostly the same, but jQuery has more options/power).

  For example, if the page's HTML had a section that looked like this:

  ```
  <div id="content">
      <p>Blah, blah, blather...</p>

      <h2>Your available actions:</h2>
      <button class="respBtn">Like</button>
      <button class="respBtn">Hate</button>
      <button id="bestOption" class="respBtn">Nuke them all</button>
  </div>
  ```

  Then selectors for the 3 buttons might be (respectively):

  1. `$("#content button.respBtn:contains('Like')");`
  2. `$("#content button.respBtn:contains('Hate')");`
  3. `$("#bestOption");` (Always use the `id`, if the element has one.)

Putting it all together, here is a **complete Greasemonkey script** that reloads and clicks:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Reload and click demo
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a major design
    change introduced in GM 1.0.
    It restores the sandbox.
*/

waitForKeyElements ("#bestOption", clickTargetButton);

function clickTargetButton (jNode) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}

//--- Reload after 1 hour (1000 * 60 * 60 milliseconds)
setTimeout (location.reload, 1000 * 60 * 60);
```