# DOM click() is not working on this button

Tags: javascript, html, click, userscripts

When I use method `click()` to click the button, the submission failed.
But, when I use the mouse to click the button on that webpage, (the submit form is same) it works.

HTML file:

```
<button xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ui-button button1"       type="submit" id="create">
    <span>
        <span>Create</span>
    </span>
</button>
```

My userscript file:

```
document.getElementById("create").click();
```

How do I click the button using HTML DOM click()?

Comment: http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/03/05/simulate-a-button-click-via-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click method does not always work.  Try sending a `click` event similarly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8192413/331508):

```
var targBtn     = document.querySelector ("#create");
var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
targBtn.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
```

---

But also beware that the button may not operate on clicks at all.   See ["Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15048223/331508).

The button may operate on `mousedown`, `mouseup`, or some combination of events.  Use the techniques from that question to activate the control.  **Link to the target page if you can't get it to work.**

Comment: thanks all the same .I solved it use settimeout.  window.setTimeout(function () {
                        document.getElementById("button-create").click();
                    }, 3000)   Because click() is too quick to get one property in the form,so it failed

Comment: Glad you got it working.  If you let us know that the content is added by javascript (AJAX), then you'll get better & faster answers next time.

Answer (score 1):

maybe instead of clicking the button.
You can submit the form in javascript as

```
document.getElementByName('form1').submit();
```

as it fulfills your requirement.

Comment: Good thinking, except that no form was indicated in the question, and the `<button>` tag was used, so there may not be a form.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the call in an anonymous self executing construct like so:

```
(function(){
    document.getElementById("create").click();
})();
```

This will simulate a `click` when the javascript is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

if at all you are flexible about value of your button then do this:

```
<button xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ui-button button1" value="submit" type="submit" id="create">

document.getButtonByValue('submit').click();
```

This works just fine.

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/zTLGB/14/#run)

Comment: This is a ***userscript*** question.  The OP normally has no control over the page's HTML in these questions.