# Greasemonkey script for clicking a button in a webpage

Tags: greasemonkey

Can someone post the grease monkey script that will automatically push a button in a webpage every 10 or 15 minutes?

Comment: You're bound to find a solution if you google for it. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192126/clicking-a-button-on-a-page-using-a-greasemonkey-userscript-in-chrome) post to see the steps you have to do before asking other people's help.

Comment: I am new to this. I tried google, however, I was unable to find the proper script. I tried the following one:

Comment: setInterval(function () {document.getElementById("refreshinput").click();}, 1000);

Comment: Ironically, now when you google this question, you see this page, which tells you to google the question.