# Tampermonkey/GreaseMonkey AutoClick -- other topics not helping

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I was wondering if anyone could help me create JavaScript for Tampermonkey on Chrome that will automatically click this button when the page loads.

And here is the code for the button:

```
<span id="container">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="5216d2a45d4185bf3f0d156a145e5aed543717388f11a12000855403a0ced24cbe4ec2cd5327e43dd0a6ee66690de3f54c55625cddfe31131c4e0e498893bfe0">
    <input type="button" class="btn-submit btn-blue large" id="button" value="Button">
</span>
```

Here is one of the things that I've tried:

```
var button = document.querySelector (
    "#button"
);
var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
button.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
```

and another

```
var btnShowObserver = function() {
  var button = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-submit')[0];
  button.getElementsByClassName('btn_confirm')[0].click();
}
```

another

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("button").click();
}
```

I have read things from 
[Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site)
to
[Clicking a button on a page using a Greasemonkey/userscript in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192126/clicking-a-button-on-a-page-using-a-greasemonkey-userscript-in-chrome)

And I am still struggling I think it's something to do with the format of the button (it has no div and most code I've seen is referring to that.)

Any ideas? I've tried my best but I am not overly familiar with javascript

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to "feed creature", close the popup, then click "next"?

Comment: Just click feed creature. There should be no popup

Comment: If you can also add clicking next that would be cool, but at the moment just clicking feed would be spectacular

Comment: Have you tried using `.click()`? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp

Comment: That's HTML. I'm pretty sure Tampermonkey only uses javascript. So how would I implement that HTML on the site?

Comment: `.click()` *is* JavaScript.  HTML is HyperText **Markup** Language, it is a markup language and not a scripting language.  The first code block you used was HTML.  What you are looking for is `document.getElementById("feed_button").click()`, which you already have in your question.  I am assuming that since it is inside a function, you forgot to call the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code from your question,

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("button").click();
}
```

will work.

I am assuming that since it is inside a [`function`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp), you forgot to call the function with `myFunction()`.

Or, the easier way to do this, is to remove the function altogether, and change it to the following.

```
document.getElementById("button").click();
```