# How to force chrome to download files not opening them?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts

I am using window.location.href="*link*.mp4" in a userscript in chrome tampermonkey but rather than starting the download chrome is opening the file and starts playing it. I have a file link in a variable and i also use idm if there's any way to trigger the through idm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try **download** attribute ?

> Example Download file when clicking on the link (instead of navigating
>   to the file):
>
> `<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>`

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: if i add this line in the html page then how will i click it using jquery or javascript

Comment: @tusharsinghal May be using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192126/clicking-a-button-on-a-page-using-a-greasemonkey-userscript-in-chrome

Answer (score 2):

Try the HTML5 download attribute

```
<a href="myfile" download>click to download</a>
```

This opens a "save as" dialog regardless of file type.

Comment: can only use html dom and javascript in userscript

Answer (score 2):

The download attribute specifies that the target will be downloaded when a user clicks on the hyperlink.

```
<a href="filename.mp4" download>Download File</a>
```

Try working JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/balaji_mitkari/xpu9yrug/

Comment: Just be aware that this is supported only modern IE versions (from IE13 which is Edge)

http://caniuse.com/#feat=download