# getting download link with presigned s3 url instead of playing link

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am currently generating s3 presigned url links with this code. It works fine but when I open the link it plays the .wav file in chrome. I just want it to download to my computer. Anyway I can modify this code to do that or add anything?

```
  const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: myBucket,
    Key: myKey,
    Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
  });
  resolve(url)
```

Thanks

Comment: Try this: [javascript - How to force chrome to download files not opening them? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887975/how-to-force-chrome-to-download-files-not-opening-them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the query parameter `response-content-disposition=attachment`. Look at this examples, specifically this one "**Sample Request: Parameters altering response header values**" here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html